# Servo control with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I will track an object according to the coordinates that I read from OpenCV. The thing is that: in order to turn my servo 120 degrees in the positive way, I need to send 3300 more to servo. (for 1 degree I need to send 27.5 more to servo).

Now I need to find a relation with the coordinates that I read from OpenCV and the value I need to send to servo. However I could not understand OpenCV's coordinates. For example I do not change object's height, I only decrease the distance between the object and the camera, in that case, only z value should decrease however it seems like x value also changes significantly. What is the reason for that?

In case, I have a problem with my code (maybe x is not changing, but I am reading it wrong), could you please give me information about OpenCV coordinates and how to interpret it? As I said in the beginning, I need to find a relation like how many degrees turn of my servo correspond to how much change in the balls X coordinates that I read from OpenCV?

Regards

edit1 for @FvD:

```
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < circles->total; i++)
    {

        float *p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
        printf("Ball! x=%f y=%f r=%f\n\r",p[0],p[1],p[2] );
        CvPoint center = cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1]));
        CvScalar val = cvGet2D(finalthreshold, center.y, center.x);

        if (val.val[0] < 1) continue;
        cvCircle(frame,  center, 3,             CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, CV_AA, 0);
        cvCircle(frame,  center, cvRound(p[2]), CV_RGB(255,0,0),  3, CV_AA, 0);
        cvCircle(finalthreshold, center, 3,             CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, CV_AA, 0);
        cvCircle(finalthreshold, center, cvRound(p[2]), CV_RGB(255,0,0),  3, CV_AA, 0);
    }
```

Comment: What kind of coordinates are you talking about? Are you using a stereo camera setup? What do the coordinates refer to and how are they calculated? Do you mean the image coordinates of the ball's center and its disparity?

Comment: @FvD I am using a webcam attached to servo. My object is circular and here is what I use to get its center's coordinates: 'cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);' now according to these coordinates, I need to find how much I shall turn my servo if for example the object displaces x amount.

Comment: That's not very useful, and almost like saying "x and y are integers" - that command only retrieves an object from the sequence "circles", it doesn't say anything about the way the coordinates you use are calculated. What is the actual setup, and what kind of coordinates are you talking about? Are they real-world or image coordinates?

Comment: Just to be more clear: There are no native "OpenCV coordinates", although you could mean the row and column of an image matrix. You have to find the place in your code where those coordinates are defined (I'm guessing you didn't write it yourself).

Comment: @FvD you are right. I did not write that part of the code. I found it on the internet and according to the printf output, I thought I was reading the opencv coordinates of the object. So, what are those coordinates, what do they mean? (I added that part of the code by editing my question)

Comment: That piece of code only reads out the ball's image coordinates from a sequence. I'll try to make a helpful answer out of this.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are no OpenCV coordinates, but you will frequently use the columns and rows of an image matrix as image coordinates.

If you have calibrated your camera, you can transform those image coordinates to real-world coordinates. In the general case, you cannot pinpoint the location of an object in space with a single camera image, unless you have a second camera (stereo vision) or supplementary information about the scene, e.g. if you are detecting objects on the ground and you know the orientation and position of your camera relative to the ground plane. In that case, moving your ball towards the camera would result in unexpected movement because the assumption that it is lying on the ground is violated.

The coordinates in the code snippet you provided are image coordinates. The third "coordinate" is the radius of the circular blob detected in the webcam image and the first two are the column and row of the circle's center in the image.

I'm not sure how you are moving the ball in your test, but if the center of the ball stays stationary in your images and you still get differing x coordinates, you should look into the detection algorithm you are using.